# How do I set dissipating:true and maxIntensity:10 for HeatmapTileProvider on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, heatmap

I wanted to set dissipating:true and maxIntensity:10 for  HeatmapTileProvider as i read it would solve an other issue i am facing with google maps. I cant seem to understand where is should insert this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.